# Why won't my code display results from an online database? How to make item in ListView clickable to new page showing results?

Tags: java, android, json, listview

i'm trying to create a movie app that searches for movies (working correctly), then displays a listview of the movies (working correctly), and when the item in the listview is clicked, it then opens up to another activity (working correctly), to display json results in a readable format of that particular film (not working correctly) - the results don't even come up.

Comment: `RelativeLayout cannot be cast to TextView at MoviePage.onCreate(MoviePage.java:52)`

The data passing problem is solved. It is a whole new question. Your xml is not consistent with java code, Check out 52nd line of MoviePage.java, according to this error message there should be a `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.blah_blah)` while in the layout xml file, `blah_blah` is id of a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: fixed that but data is still not showing up in the TextView I assigned on movie page. it just says new text.. unless i used the wrong thing to show the data..

Comment: have i used the wrong url to fetch results?

Comment: I don't know. check if data is sent to the `MoviePage` correctly. You can put a `System.out.println(finalJsonResult);` in `ResultsActivity` and `System.out.println(jsonResult + " ---- index: " + index);` on `MoviePage` activity. If they match, this question is completely answered and the other problems should be debugged separately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Movie page has no way to know what to show. The code just opens it up, not giving it further information about what should be displayed inside it.

You can pass these data in the intent that opens Movie page, i.e. these two lines of code in results activity:

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, MoviePage.class);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

using `putExtra` method in intent, you can do this, before calling `startActivity`:

```
newActivity.putExtra("index", position);
newActivity.putExtra("json result", jsonResult);
```

and to get these values and use them in `onCreate` method of `MoviePage`:

```
int index = 0;
String jsonResult = "[]";
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    index = extras.getInteger("index");
    jsonResult = extras.getString("json result");
}
```

of course it can be written in a better more robust and efficient way, but i wanted to keep the amount of change in the code small.

To overcome the inner class and final thing, there is a little trick. You should create a copy of `jsonResult` that is `final` and use that variable in the `OnItemClickListener` instance.

```
String jsonResult = db.getResult(keyword);
if (jsonResult == null) {
    jsonResult = runSearch(keyword);
}
final String finalJsonResult = jsonResult;

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, MoviePage.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("index", position);
        newActivity.putExtra("json result", finalJsonResult); // Note use of "final" copy
        startActivity(newActivity);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. i tried this and my app crashed.

Comment: @Z.iq why? did you put `putExtra` calls before `Intent newActivity = new ....` ? Or maybe jsonResult is too long to be passed inside an intent. What's the error message?

Comment: error: local variable jsonResult is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final.

Comment: Well, this is a compile error not crash. You should create a `final` copy of jsonResult outside the on item click listener and use that copy in `putExtra`.

Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850907/local-variable-needs-to-be-declared-final

Comment: please accept my apologies for saying it was a crash. i declared it as final but then the code here 'jsonResult = runSearch(keyword);' says cannot assign a value to final variable 'jsonResult'

Comment: @Z.iq No problem :-) I'll update my answer to add more explanation